# Getting wordpress pagination error on localhost but working fine on dev

Tags: wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming

( **! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function cvf_demo_pagination_load_posts() in C:\wamp64\www\capitalsmartcareers\wp-content\themes\ismart-careers\plugins\ismart\ismart.php on line 277**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix this issue after update the php version.This error occur due to latest php version and its working fine on php 5.2 .